# export admin data to sql or csv

Tags: django, django-admin, export-to-excel

In django admin, I visualize data from several models as seen in the below image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KnX7.png)

Would it be possible to export this data as sql or json or csv?

1. I tried to use the django import_export library but it exported only data belonging to one of the models and not all fields and foreign keys.

2. As an alternative, I created an sql view but I am not sure if it is possible to export the rows corresponding to a VIEW

Below is the admin class:

```
class AccidentsAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id_acc', 'text_acc', 'date_acc', 'source_acc', 'victimnb_acc', 'injurednb_acc', 'type_acc', 'category_acc', 'get_location', 'get_cf', 'get_municipality', 'get_district', 'show_images_url')
    search_fields = ("text_acc",)
    ordering = ('-date_acc',)

    def get_location(self, obj):
        return obj.id_loc.name_loc

    def show_images_url(self, obj):
        return '<a target="_blank" href="%s">%s</a>' % (obj.imagesurl_acc, obj.imagesurl_acc)
    show_images_url.allow_tags = True

    def get_municipality(self, obj):
        return obj.id_loc.id_mun.name_m


    def get_district(self, obj):
        return obj.id_loc.id_mun.id_d.name_d


    def get_cf(self, obj):
        return obj.id_loc.id_cf.acs_name



admin.site.register(Accidents, AccidentsAdmin)
```

Comment: maybe [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [export function](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/main/import_export/resources.py#L920) in Resource Class of Django-Import-Export package.

You can override the function to customize results.

If I were you, I override just export_resource function.

If you upload your codes, I can help you more.

Comment: I updated my post and shared the code